# Concatenate string rows of a data frame only in specific indices

Tags: r, concatenation

Suppose we have a data frame with two columns, one character, one numeric:

```
df <- data.frame(chr = letters[1:10],
             ind = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA))

   chr ind
1    a  NA
2    b  NA
3    c   1
4    d  NA
5    e  NA
6    f  2
7    g  NA
8    h  NA
9    i   3
10   j  NA
```

How would you paste the rows of the `chr` column taking each time only rows between non-`NA` indices in `ind`?

I want the first rows up until the first non-`NA` ignored, then we encounter `ind` = 1, then concatenate "d" and "e", then we encounter `ind` = 2, then concatenate "g" and "h", etc. To create:

```
newChar
"d e"
"g h"
"j"
```

How would you do this without a for loop?

Comment: you asked the question and within the minute you figured out the solution, wrote all the code below and posted it here?

Comment: No, I wrote the question, then thought I must be able to solve it, then thought my solution may benefit others, and posted both question and answer. Is that wrong according to SO "laws"? Tell me and I'll delete everything.

Comment: fair enough. I dont know the rules, it just confused me a bit ;)

Comment: Also according to the "rules" I can't accept my own answer until two days have passed, I'm assuming in order to let others come up with potentially better solutions. They've thought of everything!

Comment: Yeah, what you've done here is fine according to SO norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it. The trick is to use `zoo::na.locf` to fill up the `NA` values and then `group_by` and `paste`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
  mutate(bool = is.na(ind), groupID = na.locf(ind, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(bool & !is.na(groupID)) %>% group_by(groupID) %>%
  summarise(newChr = paste(chr, collapse = " ")) %>%
  select(newChr)
```